# GAE backend instance with deferred

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using `urlfetch` via `deferred.defer`. I get a timeout error. I've read to use the backend instances if your tasks need more time and grunt. In the documentation on [push tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) it shows you how to do this:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/my/worker/', params={'key': key}, target='1.backend1')
```

But I can find no examples of how to `target` a backend instance with [deferred.defer](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, use the _target parameter, e.g.:

```
deferred.defer(func, key=key, _target='1.backend1')
```