# dispatch.yaml not always routing Deferred Task Queues to correct module

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue, deferred-execution, gae-module

I have a `dispatch.yaml` file that is supposed to route deferred Task Queue requests on the `/_ah/queue/deferred` path to a module instance with more memory.  However, the requests are not consistently being routed.

See this [doc page for a primer on deferred tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Deferred_tasks) (they are a sub-type of task queue tasks).

Here is my `dispatch.yaml`:

```
dispatch:
- url: "*/_ah/queue/deferred"
  module: deferred

- url: "*/cron/*"
  module: deferred

- url: "*/ocr/cron/*"
  module: deferred
```

The problem is that while the above dispatch file seems to work most of the time, it does not work all of the time. That is, sometimes requests on the `/_ah/queue/deferred` get routed to the default module instead of the deferred module.

### Screenshots

Here is a screenshot of my logs on the "deferred" module. Notice that the URLs to the deferred path get properly dispatched:

[image: Image of Deferred Module]

---

But here is the screenshot of the default module's logs. Notice that it too is getting this path routed to it:
[image: Image of Default Module]

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Reserved_URLs

Comment: Thanks, but that says the `/_ah/` URLs are reserved for handlers. It says nothing about dispatching. You should be able to dispatch task queues to specific modules.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forgot to add `target`?

```
deferred.defer(dosomething, _target="deferred")
```

More info
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#target

Related question 
[GAE backend instance with deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253321/gae-backend-instance-with-deferred)